# Mongoose: Define schema for a complex field containing objectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a mongoDB record field called `taxonomies` which is an `object` and each of it's property contains an array of single/multiple mongo `objectId` which reference to other documents. **The property keys are dynamic and cannot be hard-coded**.

```
"taxonomies": {
      "job-region": [
        "5ef4ad0b7f6b7c001df895b7"
      ],
      "salary-slabs": [
        "5ef4ad657f6b7c001df895ca",
        "5ef4ad657f6b7c001df895cc",
        "5ef4ad657f6b7c001df895cd"
      ],
      "experience": []
 },
```

Given the above document format I want to define mongoose schema definition in such way so that I can use the `.populate()` method on the query afterwards. I've tried following schema definition but since the field is not a simple string of a single ID, it does not work with populate.

```
// Schema Definition
const JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    taxonomies: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Taxonomy",
      required: true,
    },
});
```

Any idea how to define it so I can use the `populate()` method? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId]`

Comment: I've tried it, but it does not seems to be working. May be I'm using the `.populate()` method wrong. I'm doing it like `model.find({}).populate('taxonomies')`. Is it wrong?

Comment: I looked at the wrong field, it's more complex so you should define all the fields of taxonomies too

Comment: What exactly do you want to populate? `job-region` and `salary-slabs` right? Do these have their own models and schemas?

Comment: @thammada.ts I've updated the question. The property keys (within 'taxonomies' object) are dynamic and cannot be hard-coded. And I want to populate ids from within each object key.

Comment: If they are dynamic, you can't use mongoose schema for that, and you can't use populate as well. The objective of having a schema is to provide predictable structures. You can allow the storage of dynamic objects using `Schema.Types.Mixed`, but that means there is no schema for that object at all

Comment: @thammada.ts Thanks for your help. I've resorted to storing whole taxonomy record (which only contains a couple of fields), instead of ID only. This way I don't really need to populate taxonomies field.